# Full screen-like Mail.app compose pane

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, fullscreen

If you compose a message in Mail.app in full screen you get something that looks like a modal view controller on iPad. But what is it in the Mail application on OSX Lion? How do you accomplish something like that?

Is it something custom made for mail? Or is it something that's available to all developers?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there isn't. But I guess it isn't too hard to code.
Just create a new window and add it as a sub-window of your main window using the addChildWindow:ordered: method.
You can do the animation with setFrame:display:animate: